# What could be disturbing DNS lookup on the local network?

Tags: macos, networking, router, dns, dhcp

Three windows computers setup to use hard coded `8.8.4.4` and `208.67.220.220` as DNS servers are not experiencing any problems. These servers were found using the DNS benchmark utilitiy found [here](https://code.google.com/p/namebench/).

Several Mac OS X computers setup to receive DNS settings from the router using DHCP are having intermittent problems. The DNS servers they receive include a DNS server on the local network. Some Samsung devices (a Galaxy S2 and a Tab 3) that also receive DNS configuration via DHCP are also having problems.

If I try to setup the Mac OS X computers to also use the same hard coded DNS servers as the windows computers, it does not work. Names do not resolve.

Ping and SSH and browsing works fine from all devices as long as I know the IP address of the server I want to communicate with.

When DNS stops working, it continues not working until I restart either of two routers (`A`, `B`) connected in series to the internet, as in `local network <-> router A <-> router B <-> internet`.

It then continues working for several hours, and then suddenly stops working.

**What could be causing these intermittent DNS problems? 
How can I diagnose the problem and find the cause?**

Answer (score 0):

Even though you get 2 DNS servers, only the first is always used unless that server does not respond. The second DNS server is a fallback server.

Given that the first DNS server is your router, your router is the cause for your DNS server.

8.8.4.4 is the primary server from the other devices, which is google's DNS server.

If this keeps failing, either change the DNS manually to use 8.8.4.4 (or 8.8.8.8) or try a firmware upgrade.

Note your router might just be failing and might need replacement.

Also, it is not a good idea to have 2 routers in series in your network. Is there a reason why you have this?